# Pass payment to from customers to people using PayPal Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal

I want to use PayPal Android SDK on my Android app. The problem is that I don't sure if it has the kind of features I need.

What I need is a dynamic payment service (for example, like Stripe Connect) which uses PayPal SDK. What I mean by 'dynamic' is that I would be able to set a custom recipient to who gets the transactioned money.

I've seen [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/) PayPal MPL guide, but unfortunately there is a message in it, says it is restricted for selected partners and should not be integrated in new apps.

I've checked also about Braintree v.zero, but it isn't supported in my country.

Is there a way to use PayPal Native Android SDK to create a custom recipient payment on an Android app?

Comment: Hi Ido - what it 'sounds' like you're looking to do is adaptive with PayPal payments, however this method is only available in the U.S; what you are seeing with the MPL Guide as well. What you may want to try is the BrainTree SDK  with v.0 as it has PayPal as a method and maybe available in your country. https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/introducing-braintree-vzero/. Again, this is an optional resource but may be worth looking at. Hope this helps 8^)

Comment: @GeekNinja The problem is that Braintree v.zero isn't available in my country. Is there any other option?